# Upload Image from Expo App Assets to Sever in Production

Tags: android, expo, react-native, assets

I have an image in my Expo app assets and I can access it with the following code:

```
const asset = Asset.fromModule(require("...")); 
await asset.downloadAsync();
const localUri = asset.localUri;
```

Now I want to upload this image to a server with a fetch request:

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('photo', { uri: localUri, name: "photo", type });
fetch("/endpoint", {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
      headers: {'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}
)
```

This works while using the development server but **fails after building the Android .apk**.

The `localUri` in both cases (on Android):

```
Development: file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/<username>/ExponentAsset-<hexstring>.jpg
Production: asset:///asset_<hexstring>.jpg
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay I fixed the issue by passing the `localUri` through a `expo-image-manipulator` and then using the new uri for the fetch command.
The image manipulator changes the uri from a `asset:///...` to a `file:///` uri.

No idea why it did not work previously.

Comment: Could you give a code example on "passing the localUri through a expo-image-manipulator"?

Comment: show the code here